# Write to file without write permission in C?

Tags: c

I want to create a file and the file has no write permission like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

main()
{
    int fd;
    fd=open("xxx",O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_APPEND,S_IRUSR);
    if(fd==-1)
        return 0;
    else
        if(write(fd,"created",7)==-1)
            return 0;
    if(close(fd)==-1)
        return 0;
    printf("OK");
}
```

I ran executable file and notice that the file **xxx** could be written to. Of cource, when I ran executable after first time, it worked like I expect when it could't be written to.

But how can I make the file **xxx** even can't be written to in first time (when it is created).

Comment: What do you think `O_WRONLY` means ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want `write(fd,"created",7)` to fail?

Comment: Use `perror` to handle failure of `open` or `write` or `close`  (at least during debugging phase).

Comment: This is just test code. I think when we set file permission S_IRUSR mean the file xxx had only READ permission, but in first time I ran executable file the file **xxx** has "created" line. I think when a file has only READ permission, I can't be written to.

Comment: Your question contradicts "you want to write without permission or you don't want that "?

Comment: Sorry for confuse question, I don' want to write to this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand author's intent. He want to test the usage of `S_IRUSR`. I will explain why it doesn't work at first time.

At first let us resolve your question. you can just remove `O_WRONLY` and `O_APPEND` flag, and add `O_RDONLY` flag or not. Codes are following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main() {
    int fd;
    fd = open("xxx", O_CREAT|O_RDONLY, S_IRUSR);
    // or
    // fd = open("xxx", O_CREAT, S_IRUSR);
    if (fd == -1) {
        printf("open failed\n");
        return 0;
    } else {
        if (write(fd, "created", 7) == -1) {
            printf("write failed\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    if (close(fd) == -1) {
        printf("close failed\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("OK\n");
}
```

then execute the program whenever, it will always says "write failed", and "xxx" is empty.

> $ ls
>   test.c
>   $ make test
>   cc     test.c   -o test
>   $ ls
>   test  test.c
>   $ ./test
>   write failed
>   $ ls
>   test  test.c  xxx
>   $ cat xxx
>   $ ./test
>   write failed

you said:

> Of cource, when I ran executable after first time, it worked like I expect when it could't be written to.

in fact, if use your code, ran after first time, it is not couldn't be written to, it is not be open.

> $ ls
>   test  test.c
>   $ ./test
>   OK
>   $ ls
>   test  test.c  xxx
>   $ cat xxx
>   created
>   $ ./test
>   open failed

Then let us face the more important question, why `S_ISUSR` doens't work at first time. let us run 'man 2 open', it says:

> Note that this mode  applies  only  to  future accesses of the newly created file; the open() call that creates a read-only file may well return a read/write file descriptor.

It means `S_ISUSR` only works after first time. Even `S_ISUSR` is read only, but in fact still return read/write permission, the final permission depends on the flags, if the flag is `O_WRONLY`, it can only write when create, if the flag is `O_RDONLY`, it can only read when create.

let's do a test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main() {
    int fd;
    char buf[10];
    fd = open("xxx", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR);
    if (fd == -1) {
        printf("open failed\n");
        return 0;
    } else {
        if (write(fd, "created", 7) == -1) {
            printf("write failed\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    if (read(fd, buf, 7) == -1) {
        printf("read failed\n");
        return 0;
    } else {
        printf(buf);
    }
    if (close(fd) == -1) {
        printf("close failed\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("OK\n");
}
```

and result is expected, at first time, when file create, if has write permission and has no read permission, after first time, it open failed:

> $ ls
>   test.c
>   $ make test
>   cc     test.c   -o test
>   $ ./test
>   read failed
>   $ ./test
>   open failed
>   $ cat xxx
>   created

And I can understand why they design the mode parameter only work after first time. You think, if `S_IRUSR` works when file create, then the file is always empty and read only, it has no sense.

Answer (score 3):

You should remove:

> ```
> O_WRONLY
> ```

And it should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void){
    int fd;
    fd=open("test.sh",O_CREAT|O_APPEND,S_IRUSR);

    if(fd==-1)
        return 0;
    else
        if(write(fd,"created",7)==-1)
            return 0;
    if(close(fd)==-1)
        return 0;
    printf("OK");

    return 0;
}
```

And if you try to write that file, you will get:

> ```
> [ Error writing test.sh: Permission denied ]
> ```

Anyway, on my Linux machine if I wanna check that file, I will do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

void fileCheck(const char *fileName){

    if(!access(fileName, F_OK )){
        printf("The File %s\t Found\n",fileName);
    }else{
        printf("The File %s\t not Found\n",fileName);
        exit(1);
    }

    if(!access(fileName, R_OK )){
        printf("The File %s\t can be read\n",fileName);
    }else{
        printf("The File %s\t cannot be read\n",fileName);
    }

    if(!access( fileName, W_OK )){
        printf("The File %s\t it can be Edited\n",fileName);
    }else{
        printf("The File %s\t it cannot be Edited\n",fileName);
    }

    if(!access( fileName, X_OK )){
        printf("The File %s\t is an Executable\n",fileName);
    }else{
        printf("The File %s\t is not an Executable\n",fileName);
    }
}

int main (void){
   char *fileName = "test.sh";

    fileCheck(fileName);

   return 0;
}
```

And the output says:

> ```
> The File test.sh   Found
> The File test.sh     can be read
> The File test.sh     it cannot be Edited
> The File test.sh     is not an Executable
> ```

Comment: Ok, I get it. I thought when fopen created file with only READ permission, so even if we set O_WRONLY mode, we couldn't write to created file.